# allprojects missing from build.gradle

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Whenever I create a new project, build.gradle doesn't seem to contain allprojects. When I try to add it manually to add a new repository, I get :

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while creating new project in Android studio. allProjects was missing from gradle. i had to add

```
flatDir {
  dirs 'libs'
}
```

to my project.
i solved this issue by adding it into

> settings.gradle

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```